# Rails 3 don't find index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a little trouble here with Rails 3.

I've created a controller called Admin. I've also defined a method called index and a view in app/views/admin/index.html.erb.

The problem is that when i go to http://localhost/myapp/admin i get a "Route not Found Error", but when I go to http://localhost/myapp/admin/index i get to the page I want.

I'm posting some links to the code, so you can check if there is any error, ok?

http://pastebin.com/UctUq44G

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your routes.

There is no route for 'admin/'. This will add additional routes needed.

```
resources :admin
```

If your intention is to simply have semi static pages you can add

```
get 'admin'
```

Also some handy information :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: No, this specifies that 'admin/index' in the url should load that action. There is currently no default action defined for 'admin' which is where the issue is.